# Checking if a general link is empty within a partial view

Tags: mvc

I can display a link from a field but I only want to display the link if it's been filled out by the user.  I tried surrounding by a conditional statement and checking for the field being null, but even when I don't have the field populated it comes back as true.  Here's the code:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation

@model Sitecore.Data.Items.Item
@if (Html.Sitecore().Field("External Link", Model) != null)
        {
            @Html.Sitecore().Field("External Link", Model, new { text = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Title", Model) })

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember the details, but it looks like Html.Sitecore().Field() returns HTML, which is not what you want to test. Get the actual Item and test item.Fields[ "External Link" ] or item[ "External Link" ]; as Dan Sinclair says, the latter will never actually be null.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get this working by just referring directly to the field rather than using the Sitecore helper function, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore won't return `null` when you get a field value. Instead, check for an empty string:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.Sitecore().Field("External Link", Model)))
{
    @Html.Sitecore().Field("External Link", Model, new { text = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Title", Model) })
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like this already, but it didn't work.  Intellisense says that it can't convert from system.web.htmlstring to string and there's a runtime error ( CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments).  Even if I tack on a toString(), it returns true (that the string is empty) regardless of whether there's a link or not.